# How to reference map created in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

I am following this guide:
https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/maps-platform-101-android#9

and I am trying to get a map in a fragment. I have the map successfully working but right now when the map opens, it defaults to showing Africa at a really high-level view. I want the map to default to opening to my City at a much more local level.

My xml file for the fragment looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewNearbyFragment">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:mapId="{my_map_id}"
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the Kotlin file corresponding to the same fragment looks like:

```
class ViewNearbyFragment : Fragment() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        (fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(
            R.id.map_fragment
        ) as? SupportMapFragment)?.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
            
            // Ensure all places are visible in the map.
            googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
                val bounds = LatLngBounds.builder()
                bounds.include(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 20))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_nearby, container, false)
    }
}
```

I am never entering the block that follows the getMapAsync call and I am not sure why. How can I access the map that was created in the xml file? or better yet, how can I change default values associated with this map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems with your code:

1. `onCreate()` runs before `onCreateView` as per the [Fragment lifecycle guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states). This means that your `FragmentContainerView` hasn't been inflated (and your `SupportFragmentFragment` hasn't been created) when your `onCreate` code runs. Code you want to run after `onCreateView` should be moved to `onViewCreated()`.
2. You're using the wrong FragmentManager - the deprecated `fragmentManager` is the `FragmentManager` that the fragment is attached to (that's why it was deprecated for the much more descriptive `parentFragmentManager` name). The fragment you've created is a 'child fragment' (as per the [FragmentManager guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#access)) so you need to use the `childFragmentManager`.

Your fixed code would look like:

```
class ViewNearbyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_nearby, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        (childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
            R.id.map_fragment
        ) as? SupportMapFragment)?.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
            
            // Ensure all places are visible in the map.
            googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
                val bounds = LatLngBounds.builder()
                bounds.include(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 20))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Very detailed and clear answer. Could I ask how I can change the zoom level? I plugged in lat and long and lng exactly what I was looking for. It is zoomed all the way in though. I thought the parameter that I set to 20 was for that but changing that does not appear to change anything.

Comment: Actually I just found:
```googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(0.0, 0.0), 10.0f))``` which does the trick